# How to change the layout clicking button in jung

Tags: java, jbutton, jung, jung2

I am using an SpringLayout2 for my graphical visualization. I have added Jbutton in order to change the layout by clicking this button.How can do this? can i do with LayoutTransition?. Ive tried the following code.

```
    JButton layout1 = new JButton("Layout");
    layout1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            LayoutTransition<String, Edge> lt = new LayoutTransition<String, Edge>(
                    vv, layout, radialLayout);
            Animator animator = new Animator(lt);
            animator.start();
            vv.setGraphLayout(new StaticLayout(layout.getGraph(), layout));
            vv.repaint();

        }

    });
```

But I am getting error as **"Show Console view encountered a problem"**. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: you might try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=show+console+view+has+encountered+a+problem